# Is $f(t):=\inf\lbrace x : F(x,t)<\phi(t) \rbrace $ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Assume $F:{\rm I\!R}\times[0,\infty)\rightarrow {\rm I\!R}$ is non-decreasing function for all fixed $t$,  $F(x,t)\leq F(y,t)$, $ \forall t\geq 0, x \in {\rm I\!R}, x\geq y,$ and 
$\phi : [0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,1]$ is continuous, with property $\phi(0)=1 \geq \phi(s) \geq \phi(t)>0,  \forall t>s\geq 0.$

Under this assumptions, is the following function continuous? $$f(t):=\inf\lbrace x : F(x,t)<\phi(t) \rbrace, \quad \forall t>0 $$

Comment: It seems that there is a typo regarding $F$. Is $F$ non-decreasing? non-increasing?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is non-increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Danny Park-Keung Chan said in the comment, $F$ should be non-increasing, otherwise $f(t)$ will always be $-\infty$ as long as $\{x:F(x,t)<\phi(t)\}$ is not empty.

$f(t)$ is not necessarily continuous.

Consider the counterexample
$$
F(x,t)=
\begin{cases}
\mathrm{e}^{-tx},&\text{if }t\text{ is rational,}\\
\mathrm{e}^{-2tx},&\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$
and $\phi(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-t}$, then for $t>0$,
$$
F(x,t)<\phi(t) \Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x>1,&\text{if }
t\text{ is rational,}\\
x>\frac{1}{2},&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore 
$$
f(t)=\inf\{x:F(x,t)<\phi(t)\}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }t\text{ is rational,}\\
\frac{1}{2},&\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$
which is not continuous.